# How to install the library pyopencl in Qgis python?

Tags: python, qgis, pyopencl

There is a module in Qgis 2.18 For work i need to put the library Pyopencl 
How to install the library pyopencl in Qgis python ?
I tried to transfer all the files to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`
gives an error message
Through pip I installed in python 2.7 libary pyopencl. In folder

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

I transferred the library Pyopencl in folder Qgis

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages

```
    import pyopencl
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cffi_cl'
```

How can I still install a library Pyopencl in qgis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firt step is install **Pyopencl** library,follow this guide:

http://www.minho-kim.com/courses/17sp43.635/pyopencl.html

In my case,for example is:

`python -m pip install D:\fjraga\Descargas\pyopencl-2017.1+cl12-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

,after open **Qgis** and `import pyopencl` again.

[image]